# How to put double quotation mark in json value?

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have a simple problem with my json file.

That json file can describe like this:

```
{
    "motto": "<span class="text-success">IF</span> YOU FAIL, TRY AGAIN"
}
```

How to put `"` inside `motto` property ? Thanks for advice

Comment: To the answerers: Don't answer questions that are duplicates, especially ones that are obvious duplicates. Instead, vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to escape them:

```
{
    "motto": "<span class=\"text-success\">IF</span> YOU FAIL, TRY AGAIN"
}
```

just one backslash ( \ ) in front of quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the inner double quotes around the class by using a `\` like so;

```json
{
    "motto": "<span class=\"text-success\">IF</span> YOU FAIL, TRY AGAIN"
}
```

This will make it so the quotes immediately after the `\` are seen as part of the string.

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as pie. Just escape your inner quotation marks with a backslash. So, your example will look like:

```
{
    "motto": "<span class=\"text-success\">IF</span> YOU FAIL, TRY AGAIN"
}
```